# Database import in admin Control Panel

Tags: database

Is it somehow possible to import a dumped database from the admin control panel?

I'm currently dumping my database in the control panel and import the dumped file in the phpmyadmin interface.

I'd prefer dumping and importing in the control panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently – if you want to, you can [add a feature request.](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests)

In the meantime, if you're on a Mac I recommend using [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) for all your importing (and other database related) needs.